# Am I calculating this complex integral correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_C (z+\bar z )^3\,dz$$

C being the unit circle

What I did was:

$\int_c(2Re(z))^3\,dz$

$\gamma(t)=cos(t)+isin(t)$

$\gamma'(t)=icos(t)-sin(t)$

I got it to the form $\int_0^{2\pi}8cos^3(t)\cdot(icost-sint)dt$ which seems like an hassle to calculate, is there an easier way of solving this or am I doing it properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $\int_0^{2\pi}8\cos^3(t)\sin(t)dt=0$, the remain integral $8i\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^4(t)dt$ is not so hard.

Answer (score 1):

on the unit circle, $\bar z = z^{-1}$.

Now $(z + z^{-1})^3$ is a meromorphic function on the unit disk with a pole of order $3$ at $0$ with residue $3$, so the integral is $6i\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

You may write $cos^3t=\frac{1}{4}(cos3t+3 cos t)$then as $\int_0^{2\pi}cos 3t sint=0 $and $\int_0^{2\pi}cos 3t cos t=0 $and etc.it remains $8i\frac{3}{4} $$\int_0^{2\pi}cos^2t dt$ that equals to $6{\pi}i$.